# Woocommerce API documentation for Postman

Tags: woocommerce, postman, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Is there any Woocommerce API documentation that I can import to Postman with one click? I have this documentation [Woo API](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs) but this is not possible to import in Postman.